# rewrite to subfolders htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to deploy a site using Jekyll. For convenience I wan't to:

- Clone from my GitHub repo
- build with Jekyll
- redirect access to the _site folder

I've been looking around the web but none of the solutions I've found worked.

The url is something like:

https://example.com/repo-folder/_site/

Of course I want the visitors only to see:

https://example.com/repo-folder/

In the address bar but serve all the files of the _site folder.

What have I to write into the s htaccess file and where should it be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the repo folder you can try adding these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /+(.+?/?)_site/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R]

RewriteCond $1 !^_site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _site/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it but this does not work. It rewrites the _site folder to repo-folder.  

You can take a look here https://interface.fh-potsdam.de/eingabe-ausgabe/ 
When I call the https://interface.fh-potsdam.de/eingabe-ausgabe/_site folder it redirects to the https://interface.fh-potsdam.de/eingabe-ausgabe/ url. But I want under that url to serve the _site content.

Comment: @fabiantheblind There was a stray `%` in the second rewrite condition

Comment: still the same. Can it be a problem that the files also exist at that location? eingabe-ausgabe/_site/index.html and eingabe-ausgabe/index.html both exist. That's why the .yaml header is visible

Comment: @fabiantheblind ha, sorry, was also missing a `!`

Comment: awesome that works. Thanks a lot. Is there any good reference to learn this and understand what the rules mean?

Comment: @fabiantheblind the Apache mod_rewrite documentation also has a tutorial (may only be for apache 2.2, can't remember), can't findlink right now